# Processor speed for generating PWM at 1 MHz

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, power-electronics, microprocessor

I want to generate square pulses at around 1 MHz to drive an H-bridge inverter. Now, I want to choose a suitable microcontroller, microprocessor, or a DSP board.
I need to generate a few pulses (minimum 4) with the possibility of controlling the duty and the phase. The resolution I am aiming for is around 5 ns. I also want to execute some control logic.
What would be the minimum speed of the processor for this purpose?

For example, I have [TI MCU F28379D LaunchPad](http://www.ti.com/tool/launchxl-f28379d?jktype=tools_software) in mind which include 200 MHz [TMS320F28379D](http://www.ti.com/product/TMS320f28379D). If I can use the full 200 MHz speed, I should be able to get \$5~\rm{ns}\$ resolution. But what will be the practical resolution in a real implementation?

Comment: This sounds like something you could offload to a timer? I would have thought most of the reasonably quick micro controllers would suffice

Comment: Are you interested in a recommendation on how to select a platform or rather a specific platform recommendation? Your question asks for a speed requirement, but your comment to an answer mentions specific platform.

Comment: @Jurkstas, I edited the question to fit with the rules and deleted the comment now. in fact, if I can get recommendations on "how to select a platform", I should be able to select a specific platform.

Comment: You'll have to read the datasheets and compare timer peripherals and the maximum clock frequency **for that peripheral**. Some processors (TI is one supplier) use some interesting tricks to get as good as 150ps PWM resolution without insane clock frequencies.

Answer (score -4):

You could use something as simple as an [Arduino Nano](https://amzn.to/2TDIMJr) (main processor is an ATMega328) and run the following code ([from official arduino site](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/delaymicroseconds/)):

```
int outPin = 8;                 // digital pin 8

void setup()
{
  pinMode(outPin, OUTPUT);      // sets the digital pin as output
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(outPin, HIGH);   // sets the pin on
  delayMicroseconds(5);        // pauses for 5 microseconds
  digitalWrite(outPin, LOW);    // sets the pin off
  delayMicroseconds(5);        // pauses for 5 microseconds
}
```

The code as I've shown it here should get you to 200KHz

However, I believe that function can only go down to 3us so in reality you may not be able to quite make it to 1MHz.

Comment: Arduino default digitalWrite() is slow.

Comment: @LongPham It may be but I successfully created a simple square wave generator using this method and I tested it using a very simple hobbyist oscilloscope (https://amzn.to/2BukFWE) and it worked well enough for my purposes.  It was just an idea.